# Click & Drag a copy of a button

Tags: html, css, button, twitter-bootstrap-3, thymeleaf

I am not sure why this is happening, and it is only happening with the cancel button that has the href associated to it. Any thoughts how to fix this so that a user cannot click and drag a copy of the cancel button?

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<div id="cancelDiv" class="col-md-4" style="padding-left: 0.8rem">
                                <a id="cancelButton" class="btn btn-primary"
                                    th:href="${b2bDevLink}" target="_self"
                                    style="text-decoration: none; color: white">Cancel</a>
                            </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal href behavior.
Just add this style to your button:

```
user-drag: none; 
user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-drag: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
```